why is my file not able to find a reference to my class?
i have a Form class that brings in other classes from Controllers, Views, and Models folders. all of the class initializations work except for one.
this is how im bringing in the other folders
using VideoPlayer_Proto.Models;
using VideoPlayer_Proto.Controllers;
using VideoPlayer_Proto.Views;

and this is how i initilize the class
private PlaylistManager playlistManager = new PlaylistManager();

i keep getting this error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PlaylistManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VideoPlayer_Proto   C:\path to\project\source\repos\VideoPlayer_Proto\VideoPlayer_Proto\Views\Form1.cs  36  

the name space for the PlaylistManager is
namespace VideoPlayer_Proto.Controllers

im still learning c#, so i dont really know how to find the problem
i tried to link the file like this
private PlaylistManager playlistManager = new PlaylistManager();

but i keep getting the error
P.S.
im trying not to use the WPF tools. since im still learning i want to type out all the code and not use a click and drag tool

did you check the namespace: Ensure the PlaylistManager class is in the VideoPlayer_Proto.Controllers namespace?

yes it is.
namespace VideoPlayer_Proto.Controllers

You can try to specify the full namespace when initializing it in Form1.cs
private VideoPlayer_Proto.Controllers.PlaylistManager playlistManager = new VideoPlayer_Proto.Controllers.PlaylistManager();
`

@desboisrob no. same error. i have other files and classes referenced the exact same way, but for some reason only this one doesn't work. other than the namespace on the file is there any other reference to the name of the class? or is it just the namespace at the top?

I was able to fix it by adding
<Compile Include="Controllers\PlaylistManager.cs" />

to the .csproj file. not sure why it wasnt added automatically. and when i right click on the Solutions panel and go to Add it no longer gives me a "New Class" option. guess theres something wrong in settings or something
